# AWS CDK - Add New Security Group to an Existing VPC Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have an existing VPC Endpoint, Now using CDK, I need to add a new SecurityGroup to the existing endoint. CDK has an option to Import the endpoint using following method:

```
const vpce = InterfaceVpcEndpoint.fromInterfaceVpcEndpointAttributes(this, 'TransferVpce', {
  port: 443,
  vpcEndpointId: "vpce-EndPointID",

}
);
```

But once Imported, it does not give me an option to Update it by adding a new Security Group. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`InterfaceVpcEndpoint` returns [Connections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/Connections.html#aws_cdk.aws_ec2.Connections) where you can find your `security_groups`. Then you can create your [SecurityGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/SecurityGroup.html) and modify the rules.

Comment: Can I attach a new SecurityGroup to the endpoint? Any examples?

Comment: @Nawaz I wrote how to do it. If you want full code to be written for you, then I would suggest trying it yourself, and then making new question with the code you wrote along with any errors you get.

Comment: Does not seem to work, in fact cdk synth, seems to completely ignore the VPCE that I am trying to import. Importing an SG works fine but the same does not seem to be true with VPCE. Is the "Port" specification causing the issue?